# Excel change cell value of active worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

For an excel 2010 plugin, I need a method to change cell values of the active worksheet.

This code works, but opens a new excel window.
How can I change this, to edit the values from the active worksheet?

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objApp;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook objBook;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets objSheets;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet workSheet;


objApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
objApp.Visible = true;
objBook = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)objApp.ActiveWorkbook;

if (objBook == null)
    {
       objBook = objApp.Workbooks.Add();
    }

// get the collection of sheets in the workbook

objSheets = objBook.Worksheets;

// get the first and only worksheet from the collection of worksheets

workSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)objSheets.get_Item(1);

workSheet.Cells[1, "A"] = "wert1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I found the solution:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook objBook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets objSheets;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet workSheet;

objBook = (Workbook)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;

if (objBook == null)
    {
       objBook = objApp.Workbooks.Add();
    }

// get the first and only worksheet from the collection of worksheets

workSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)objBook.ActiveSheet;

workSheet.Cells[1, "A"] = "value1A";
```

Source:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/199576-getting-current-excel-application-or-workbook-in-c%23/

Comment: Your code is a little wrong, when you call `objSheets.get_Item(1)` it is getting the first `Worksheet` in the `Workbook`, which may not be the `Active Sheet` at the time. The correct way of doing this would be to say `objBook.ActiveSheet`. This will return the active worksheet or `Nothing` if no worksheet is `Active`.

Comment: Unless you actually need to access the remainder of the `Worksheets` within the `Workbook` you are also able to remove the `objSheets = objBook.Worksheets` call, as this would now be an unnecessary call over the interop.